# Permission bits set, but still access denied

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions

So I'm trying to execute a file with these permission bits:

`drwxr-sr-x`

But I get `zsh: permission denied`.

Since the final bit means anyone can execute, why am I unable to execute this file?

Answer (score 1):

Because it's a directory (`d`). You can't execute directories. Execute perms on a directory mean it's "browsable" and can have its contents listed out by authorized users

Comment: And `s` in the group bits means that files created in the directory will get the same group owner as the directory itself.